# Progress bar for latex-beamer

Tags: beamer

Instead of slide numbers, I find it very nice to have something like a unobtrusive progressbar at the bottom which grows each slide about (width of screen)/(slide numbers).

I've found [here](http://www.mrunix.de/forums/showpost.php?p=316577&postcount=3) (page in German) the following code snippet:

```
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% progress bar in footline
%% http://www.mrunix.de/forums/showpost.php?p=316577&postcount=3
%% -----------------------------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{lightgr}{rgb}{0.7 0.7 0.7}
\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \color{lightgr}% to color the progressbar
  \hspace*{-\beamer@leftmargin}%
  \rule{\beamer@leftmargin}{2pt}%
  \rlap{\rule{\dimexpr
      \beamer@startpageofframe\dimexpr
      \beamer@rightmargin+\textwidth\relax/\beamer@endpageofdocument}{1pt}}
  % next 'empty' line is mandatory!

  \vspace{0\baselineskip}
  {}
}
```

It work fine in the beginning, but after I added a certain number of frames, suddenly it caused the following error message:

```
! Dimension too large.
<argument> ...amer@rightmargin +\textwidth \relax 
                                                  /\beamer@endpageofdocument 
l.517 \lyxframeend
```

It took me several hours to figure out that the progress bar caused the error message, because it is thrown only when I add certain images. But I couldn't figure out any system, when there is an error and when not. Sometimes it is possible to add new frames without problems, sometimes not. Sometimes when I use pdfpages to add a page the error occurs.

I use LyX (as you can see) and the Pittsburgh theme, but I suppose such a (running) progress bar snippet would be interesting for many users (also those with other themes and without LyX).

A screenshot of a frame to illustrate the result:

[image: Screenshot]

**My Questions:**

- Is there a way to get this code more stable and compatible with any theme?
- Would it be easy to turn this into an package?
- How can I change the `\beamer@startpageofframe` to the real PDF page number? (Otherwise there are quite big and sudden jumps of the progressbar.)

(Please comment if I should provide more information, e.g. my whole LyX file.)

Comment: There is a beamer theme called metropolis (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamertheme-metropolis) which has progressbar in the section page overviews. Maybe this is helpful for you.

Comment: @math It can, ostensibly, be configured to go in the footer et al. too, via the `progressbar=foot|head|frametitle|none` package option. It doesn't seem to work for me, though.

Comment: Ah, actually, it works fine - it's just quite narrow (when not projected) and I couldn't see it! (I missed the edit window.)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Here you have some customizable progress bars (part of a project I am working on):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{pbblue}{HTML}{0A75A8}% filling color for the progress bar
\definecolor{pbgray}{HTML}{575757}% background color for the progress bar

\makeatletter
\def\progressbar@progressbar{} % the progress bar
\newcount\progressbar@tmpcounta% auxiliary counter
\newcount\progressbar@tmpcountb% auxiliary counter
\newdimen\progressbar@pbht %progressbar height
\newdimen\progressbar@pbwd %progressbar width
\newdimen\progressbar@tmpdim % auxiliary dimension

\progressbar@pbwd=\linewidth
\progressbar@pbht=1.5ex

% the progress bar
\def\progressbar@progressbar{%

    \progressbar@tmpcounta=\insertframenumber
    \progressbar@tmpcountb=\inserttotalframenumber
    \progressbar@tmpdim=\progressbar@pbwd
    \multiply\progressbar@tmpdim by \progressbar@tmpcounta
    \divide\progressbar@tmpdim by \progressbar@tmpcountb

  \begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners=2pt,very thin]

    \shade[top color=pbgray!20,bottom color=pbgray!20,middle color=pbgray!50]
      (0pt, 0pt) rectangle ++ (\progressbar@pbwd, \progressbar@pbht);

      \shade[draw=pbblue,top color=pbblue!50,bottom color=pbblue!50,middle color=pbblue] %
        (0pt, 0pt) rectangle ++ (\progressbar@tmpdim, \progressbar@pbht);

    \draw[color=normal text.fg!50]  
      (0pt, 0pt) rectangle (\progressbar@pbwd, \progressbar@pbht) 
        node[pos=0.5,color=normal text.fg] {\textnormal{%
             \pgfmathparse{\insertframenumber*100/\inserttotalframenumber}%
             \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}\,\%%
        }%
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=4ex,center,dp=1ex]{white}%
    \progressbar@progressbar%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And a close-up image of the bar:

[image]

Two little variations; first using a circle as progress indicator:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{pbblue}{HTML}{0A75A8}% color for the progress bar and the circle

\makeatletter
\def\progressbar@progressbar{} % the progress bar
\newcount\progressbar@tmpcounta% auxiliary counter
\newcount\progressbar@tmpcountb% auxiliary counter
\newdimen\progressbar@pbht %progressbar height
\newdimen\progressbar@pbwd %progressbar width
\newdimen\progressbar@rcircle % radius for the circle
\newdimen\progressbar@tmpdim % auxiliary dimension

\progressbar@pbwd=\linewidth
\progressbar@pbht=1pt
\progressbar@rcircle=2.5pt

% the progress bar
\def\progressbar@progressbar{%

    \progressbar@tmpcounta=\insertframenumber
    \progressbar@tmpcountb=\inserttotalframenumber
    \progressbar@tmpdim=\progressbar@pbwd
    \multiply\progressbar@tmpdim by \progressbar@tmpcounta
    \divide\progressbar@tmpdim by \progressbar@tmpcountb

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[pbblue!30,line width=\progressbar@pbht]
      (0pt, 0pt) -- ++ (\progressbar@pbwd,0pt);

    \filldraw[pbblue!30] %
      (\the\dimexpr\progressbar@tmpdim-\progressbar@rcircle\relax, .5\progressbar@pbht) circle (\progressbar@rcircle);

    \node[draw=pbblue!30,text width=3.5em,align=center,inner sep=1pt,
      text=pbblue!70,anchor=east] at (0,0) {\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=4ex,center,dp=1ex]{white}%
    \progressbar@progressbar%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And the close-up:

[image]

And now using a triangle as progress-indicator (inspired by the theme **Ignasi** mentioned in his answer):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{pbgray}{HTML}{575757}% background color for the progress bar

\makeatletter
\def\progressbar@progressbar{} % the progress bar
\newcount\progressbar@tmpcounta% auxiliary counter
\newcount\progressbar@tmpcountb% auxiliary counter
\newdimen\progressbar@pbht %progressbar height
\newdimen\progressbar@pbwd %progressbar width
\newdimen\progressbar@tmpdim % auxiliary dimension

\progressbar@pbwd=\linewidth
\progressbar@pbht=1pt

% the progress bar
\def\progressbar@progressbar{%

    \progressbar@tmpcounta=\insertframenumber
    \progressbar@tmpcountb=\inserttotalframenumber
    \progressbar@tmpdim=\progressbar@pbwd
    \multiply\progressbar@tmpdim by \progressbar@tmpcounta
    \divide\progressbar@tmpdim by \progressbar@tmpcountb

  \begin{tikzpicture}[very thin]
    \draw[pbgray!30,line width=\progressbar@pbht]
      (0pt, 0pt) -- ++ (\progressbar@pbwd,0pt);
    \draw[draw=none]  (\progressbar@pbwd,0pt) -- ++ (2pt,0pt);

    \draw[fill=pbgray!30,draw=pbgray] %
       ( $ (\progressbar@tmpdim, \progressbar@pbht) + (0,1.5pt) $ ) -- ++(60:3pt) -- ++(180:3pt) ;

    \node[draw=pbgray!30,text width=3.5em,align=center,inner sep=1pt,
      text=pbgray!70,anchor=east] at (0,0) {\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=5ex,center,dp=1ex]{white}%
    \progressbar@progressbar%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And the close-up:

[image]

Comment: Looks great! Would be a really great package, if it is highly customizeably! Unfortunately I get an error, I pasted it here: http://pastebin.com/yb79iMUF

Comment: @lumbric yes, the project I mentioned in my answer includes a package containing the progress bar. The error message is not caused by my code, but by the `framed` package; apparently you ran out of lengths; you can try loading the `etex` package (`\usepackage{etex}`) right after `\begin{document}`. If the problem persists, then a follow-up question with a minimal version of the offending code would be the way to go.

Comment: Nice work @GonzaloMedina: When it will be available as a package? Please notify to us also here in this site.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Is it correct that your code is missing `\makeatother`? If this is the case, where should it be added? Otherwise, this looks great!!!1 Thanks!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Perhaps you could put this into the appropriate format for inclusion in `beamer` as a theme file?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Wow great, thanks! etex solved the problem. I managed to adopt your code to my needs, it works great! Thanks!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: My last frame uses `allowframebreaks` and goes over two "pages". This confuses your code: The first of this page shows the 100% and a filled bar, the second shows 105% and the bar got an extension.

Comment: @HarishKumar I still have lots of work to do, but as soon as it's ready I'll let you know.

Comment: @Dror you're right; I initially forgot `\makeatother`; I've added it. Thanks for your kind words.

Comment: @JosephWright the prject bar is part of a bigger project, but I like your idea :-)  I'll let you know when the theme is ready.

Comment: @lumbric You're welcome! I am glad you liked the progress bar.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer could you please give me a little example of code showing the problem? After reading your comment, I did some tests with `allowframebreaks`, but I wasn't able to reproduce the odd behaviour you mentioned.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Looks as if `allowframebreaks` alone is not the problem. My last frame actually uses `[allowframebreaks,t]`. You can test the behaviour with your example if you use this options and `\lipsum[1-4]` in one frame. (And naturally load `lipsum`)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Now I am really intrigued; I can't reproduce the problem using `[allowframebreaks,t]` either... Should we perhaps continue this discussion in a chat room?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: If I have one frame consisting of 50 slides and another consisting of only one, then the progress bar will always be the same for 50 slides. Wouldnt it be better to use `\insertpagenumber` and `\insertdocumentendpage` for your `tmpcounta` and `tmpcountb` ?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I was wondering if you are finished with your progress bar package or not?

Comment: @antmw1361 almost done! I'll let you know when it's finished.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Your theme with `ball` fails for me with more than 53 slides. It finishes with `! Arithmetic overflow.
\progressbar@progressbar ...progressbar@tmpcounta 
                                                  \divide \progressbar@tmpdi...`

Comment: @Ignasi I'll do some tests to see if I can reproduce the problem, and I'll let you know the results.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I personally tried the first progress bar, it seems to have an issue when the value of tmpcounta exceeds 44 slides. For tmpcounta=45 it does not compile anymore with the error: Arithmetic overflow. I am not sure why though...

Comment: @Alain Hard to tell without some actual code. Please compose a MWE illustrating the problem and open a follow-up question.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina indeed, I will do this. I did not provide a MWE in the comments as I thought it may be a known issue.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I created a post regarding this issue: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211301/slide-number-limit-when-using-a-progress-bar

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: This is awesome, thank you! Would it be possible to add the section headings into the bar? So the `section heading` will be highlighted when arriving there during presentation?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Excuse me, I have sent you the wrong URL. This is the right one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503702/beamer-how-to-add-progress-bar-with-section-titles

Comment: Works well and looks nice. I'd like to use this in a beamer presentation in which I externalize the TikZ figures with `\usetikzlibrary{external}`. Unfortuantely, the progress bar marker doesn't work anymore when figures are externalized, do you have any pointers on that?

Answer (score 35):

For ConTeXt, I have written a module [visualcounter](https://github.com/adityam/visualcounter) that allows one to visualize any ConTeXt counter. It provides a few predefined visualizers.

See the [documentation](http://modules.contextgarden.net/dl/t-visualcounter/doc/context/third/visualcounter/visualcounter.pdf) for details. The basic usage is

```
\usemodule[visualcounter]


\definevisualcounter
  [pagevisualized] % visualizer
  [progressbar] % inherit from
  [counter=userpage]


\usevisualcounter{pagevisualizer}
```

where the first argument is the name of the visualizer that you want to define, the 2nd (optional) argument is the predefined visualizer from which you can inherit settings, and counter is the name of counter that the visualizer should display. See the `tests/` subdirectory on github for detailed examples.

The image below shows four visualizers for page numbers and itemizations.

[image]

Comment: You are a wizard in context. By reading your answers I am tempted to learn it.

Comment: @HarishKumar: I am no wizard. Most of answers just describe the basic features of ConTeXt. Do give it a try.

Comment: Can anyone help me with how to install this package?

Comment: This is for ConTeXt, not LaTeX.

Answer (score 33):

Sylvain Bouveret already developed a progressbar theme for beamer. You can find it in [his web page](http://recherche.noiraudes.net/fr/LaTeX.php). It's a 'complete' (inner, outer, color, font) theme but here you have a little example with just using `\useoutertheme{progressbar}`. Bootom triangle moves under the line according actual slide.

[image]

Answer (score 24):

Some time ago I did a progress bar, so I changed it to be used in beamer via the `\logo` command. The bar overlaps with the navigation symbols, you might want to change it if it is an issue for you:

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\Progressbar@LabelColor}{black}
    \newcommand{\Progressbar@LabelText}{Label}
    \newcommand{\Progressbar@LabelWidth}{5}
%   Farbe, Text, Breite des Labels

    \newcommand{\Progressbar@BarWidth}{10}
    \newcommand{\Progressbar@BarHeight}{1}
    \newcommand{\Progressbar@BarColor}{yellow}
    \newcommand{\Progressbar@BarBorder}{black}
%   Breite, Höhe, Schriftfarbe des Prozentsatzes, Rahmenfarbe des Fortschrittbalkens

    \newcommand{\Progressbar@TodoA}{gray}
    \newcommand{\Progressbar@TodoB}{black}
%   Farbe 1 und 2 für den unerledigten Teil 

    \newcommand{\Progressbar@DoneA}{red}
    \newcommand{\Progressbar@DoneB}{blue}
%   Farbe 1 und 2 für den erledigten Teil   

    \newcommand{\Progressbar@Direction}{LTR}
%   Modus links nach rechts oder umgekehrt; umgekehrt ist buggy (no support yet)    

    \newcommand{\Progressbar@Completion}{50}
%   Fertigstellung in Prozent   

    \define@key{Progressbar}{LabelColor}[\Progressbar@LabelColor]{\renewcommand{\Progressbar@LabelColor}{#1}}
    \define@key{Progressbar}{LabelText}[\Progressbar@LabelText]{\renewcommand{\Progressbar@LabelText}{#1}}
    \define@key{Progressbar}{LabelWidth}[\Progressbar@LabelWidth]{\renewcommand{\Progressbar@LabelWidth}{#1}}

    \define@key{Progressbar}{BarWidth}[\Progressbar@BarWidth]{\renewcommand{\Progressbar@BarWidth}{#1}}
    \define@key{Progressbar}{BarHeight}[\Progressbar@BarHeight]{\renewcommand{\Progressbar@BarHeight}{#1}}
    \define@key{Progressbar}{BarColor}[\Progressbar@BarColor]{\renewcommand{\Progressbar@BarColor}{#1}}

    \define@key{Progressbar}{BarBorder}[\Progressbar@BarBorder]{\renewcommand{\Progressbar@BarBorder}{#1}}
    \define@key{Progressbar}{TodoA}[\Progressbar@TodoA]{\renewcommand{\Progressbar@TodoA}{#1}}
    \define@key{Progressbar}{TodoB}[\Progressbar@TodoB]{\renewcommand{\Progressbar@TodoB}{#1}}

    \define@key{Progressbar}{DoneA}[\Progressbar@DoneA]{\renewcommand{\Progressbar@DoneA}{#1}}
    \define@key{Progressbar}{DoneB}[\Progressbar@DoneB]{\renewcommand{\Progressbar@DoneB}{#1}}
    \define@key{Progressbar}{Direction}[\Progressbar@Direction]{\renewcommand{\Progressbar@Direction}{#1}}

    \define@key{Progressbar}{Completion}[\Progressbar@Completion]{\renewcommand{\Progressbar@Completion}{#1}}

    \newcommand{\Progressbar}[1]%
    {   \setkeys{Progressbar}{#1}
        % Progress Bars --------------------------------------------------
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,shift={($(current page.south west)+(0.1,0.1)$)}]

            \ifthenelse{ \( \Progressbar@Completion = 0 \) \or \( \Progressbar@Completion = 100 \) }
                {   \newcommand{\TCA}{\Progressbar@TodoA}
                    \newcommand{\TCB}{\Progressbar@TodoB}
                    \newcommand{\DCA}{\Progressbar@DoneA}
                    \newcommand{\DCB}{\Progressbar@DoneB}
                }
                {   \newcommand{\TCA}{\Progressbar@TodoB !\Progressbar@Completion !\Progressbar@TodoA}
                    \newcommand{\TCB}{\Progressbar@TodoB}
                    \newcommand{\DCA}{\Progressbar@DoneA}
                    \newcommand{\DCB}{\Progressbar@DoneB !\Progressbar@Completion !\Progressbar@DoneA}
                }
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\Progressbar@Direction}{LTR}}
                {   \shade[left color=\DCA,right color=\DCB]%
                        (0,0) rectangle (\Progressbar@Completion * \Progressbar@BarWidth / 100,\Progressbar@BarHeight);
                    \shade[left color=\TCA,right color=\TCB]%
                        (\Progressbar@Completion * \Progressbar@BarWidth / 100,0)%
                        rectangle (\Progressbar@BarWidth,\Progressbar@BarHeight);
                }
                {   \shade[left color=\TCB,right color=\TCA]%
                        (0,0) rectangle (\Progressbar@Completion * \Progressbar@BarWidth / 100,\Progressbar@BarHeight);
                    \shade[left color=\DCB,right color=\DCA]%
                        (\Progressbar@Completion * \Progressbar@BarWidth / 100,0)%
                        rectangle (\Progressbar@BarWidth,\Progressbar@BarHeight);               
                }
            \draw (0,0) rectangle (\Progressbar@BarWidth,\Progressbar@BarHeight);
            \node[color=\Progressbar@BarColor] at%
                (\Progressbar@BarWidth / 10,\Progressbar@BarHeight / 2) {\Progressbar@Completion \%};
            \draw[color=white] (- \Progressbar@LabelWidth,0) -- %
                node[anchor=west,color=\Progressbar@LabelColor,text width=\Progressbar@LabelWidth]%
                {\Progressbar@LabelText} (- \Progressbar@LabelWidth,\Progressbar@BarHeight) ;
%               \typeout{todo c1 = \TCA}
%               \typeout{todo c2 = \TCB}
%               \typeout{done c1 = \DCA}
%               \typeout{done c2 = \DCB}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\makeatother

\logo   {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\wid}{\the\paperwidth/28.45276-0.2}
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prog}{100*\insertpagenumber/\insertdocumentendpage}
                \Progressbar{   LabelColor=yellow,%
                                            LabelText=,%
                                            LabelWidth=0,%
                                            BarWidth=\wid,%
                                            BarHeight=0.3,%
                                            BarColor=green,%
                                            BarBorder=black,%
                                            TodoA=orange!20!gray,%
                                            TodoB=orange!80!gray,%
                                            DoneA=blue!80!cyan,%
                                            DoneB=blue!20!cyan,%
                                            Completion=\prog%
                                        }
            }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \only<1>{Sha la la.}
    \only<2>{Shu bi du.}
    \only<3>{Tri Tra.}
    \only<4>{Trullala.}

    page - frame - totalpages : \insertpagenumber\ - \insertframenumber\ -  \insertdocumentendpage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \only<1>{One.}
    \only<2>{Zwei.}
    \only<3>{Tri.}
    \only<4>{Quattro.}
    \only<5>{Cinq.}
    \only<6>{Seis.}
    \only<7>{Siedem.}
    \only<8>{Kahdeksan.}

    page - frame - totalpages : \insertpagenumber\ - \insertframenumber\ -  \insertdocumentendpage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

### Edit 1

On popular demand by a single person, I reworked this as it was only "some kind of working". Instead of doing complicated computations with colors now I just use clipping.
RTL progression of the bar now works, furthermore you can influence the position of the percentage label.

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\Progressbar@BarWidth}{10}
    \newcommand{\Progressbar@BarHeight}{1}
    \newcommand{\Progressbar@BarColor}{yellow}
    \newcommand{\Progressbar@BarBorder}{black}
    \newcommand{\Progressbar@BarPosition}{10}
%   Breite, Höhe, Schriftfarbe des Prozentsatzes, Rahmenfarbe, Bechriftungsposition des Fortschrittbalkens

    \newcommand{\Progressbar@TodoA}{gray}
    \newcommand{\Progressbar@TodoB}{black}
%   Farbe 1 und 2 für den unerledigten Teil 

    \newcommand{\Progressbar@DoneA}{red}
    \newcommand{\Progressbar@DoneB}{blue}
%   Farbe 1 und 2 für den erledigten Teil   

    \newcommand{\Progressbar@Direction}{LTR}
%   Modus links nach rechts oder umgekehrt; umgekehrt ist buggy (no support yet)

    \newcommand{\Progressbar@Completion}{50}
%   Fertigstellung in Prozent   

    \define@key{Progressbar}{BarWidth}[\Progressbar@BarWidth]{\renewcommand{\Progressbar@BarWidth}{#1}}
    \define@key{Progressbar}{BarHeight}[\Progressbar@BarHeight]{\renewcommand{\Progressbar@BarHeight}{#1}}
    \define@key{Progressbar}{BarColor}[\Progressbar@BarColor]{\renewcommand{\Progressbar@BarColor}{#1}}

    \define@key{Progressbar}{BarBorder}[\Progressbar@BarBorder]{\renewcommand{\Progressbar@BarBorder}{#1}}
    \define@key{Progressbar}{BarPosition}[\Progressbar@BarPosition]{\renewcommand{\Progressbar@BarPosition}{#1}}    
    \define@key{Progressbar}{TodoA}[\Progressbar@TodoA]{\renewcommand{\Progressbar@TodoA}{#1}}

    \define@key{Progressbar}{TodoB}[\Progressbar@TodoB]{\renewcommand{\Progressbar@TodoB}{#1}}
    \define@key{Progressbar}{DoneA}[\Progressbar@DoneA]{\renewcommand{\Progressbar@DoneA}{#1}}
    \define@key{Progressbar}{DoneB}[\Progressbar@DoneB]{\renewcommand{\Progressbar@DoneB}{#1}}

    \define@key{Progressbar}{Direction}[\Progressbar@Direction]{\renewcommand{\Progressbar@Direction}{#1}}
    \define@key{Progressbar}{Completion}[\Progressbar@Completion]{\renewcommand{\Progressbar@Completion}{#1}}

    \newcommand{\Progressbar}[1]%
    {   \setkeys{Progressbar}{#1}
        % Progress Bars --------------------------------------------------
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,shift={($(current page.south west)+(0.1,0.1)$)}]
            \draw[draw=\Progressbar@BarBorder,ultra thick] (0,0) rectangle (\Progressbar@BarWidth,\Progressbar@BarHeight);          
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\Progressbar@Direction}{LTR}}
                {   \shade[left color=\Progressbar@TodoA,right color=\Progressbar@TodoB]%
                        (0,0)   rectangle (\Progressbar@BarWidth,\Progressbar@BarHeight);
                    \begin{scope}
                        \clip   (0,0) rectangle (\Progressbar@Completion * \Progressbar@BarWidth / 100,\Progressbar@BarHeight);
                        \shade[left color=\Progressbar@DoneA,right color=\Progressbar@DoneB]%
                            (0,0) rectangle (\Progressbar@BarWidth,\Progressbar@BarHeight);
                    \end{scope}
                }
                {   \shade[left color=\Progressbar@TodoB,right color=\Progressbar@TodoA]%
                        (0,0) rectangle (\Progressbar@BarWidth,\Progressbar@BarHeight);
                    \begin{scope}
                        \clip   ({(100-\Progressbar@Completion) * \Progressbar@BarWidth / 100},0)%
                            rectangle (\Progressbar@BarWidth,\Progressbar@BarHeight);
                        \shade[left color=\Progressbar@DoneB,right color=\Progressbar@DoneA]%
                            (0,0)   rectangle (\Progressbar@BarWidth,\Progressbar@BarHeight);               
                    \end{scope}
                }
            \node[color=\Progressbar@BarColor] at%
                (\Progressbar@BarWidth / 100 * \Progressbar@BarPosition,\Progressbar@BarHeight / 2) {\Progressbar@Completion \%};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\makeatother

\logo   {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\wid}{\the\paperwidth/28.45276-0.2}
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prog}{100*\insertpagenumber/\insertdocumentendpage}
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mybarpos}{104-\prog}
                \Progressbar{   BarWidth=\wid,%
                                            BarHeight=0.3,%
                                            BarColor=green,%
                                            BarBorder=none,%
                                            BarPosition=\mybarpos,%
                                            TodoA=orange!20!gray,%
                                            TodoB=orange!80!gray,%
                                            DoneA=blue!80!cyan,%
                                            DoneB=blue!20!cyan,%
                                            Completion=\prog,%
                                            Direction=RTL,%
                                        }
            }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \only<1>{Sha la la.}
    \only<2>{Shu bi du.}
    \only<3>{Tri Tra.}
    \only<4>{Trullala.}

    page - frame - totalpages : \insertpagenumber\ - \insertframenumber\ -  \insertdocumentendpage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \only<1>{One.}
    \only<2>{Zwei.}
    \only<3>{Tri.}
    \only<4>{Quattro.}
    \only<5>{Cinq.}
    \only<6>{Seis.}
    \only<7>{Siedem.}
    \only<8>{Kahdeksan.}

    page - frame - totalpages : \insertpagenumber\ - \insertframenumber\ -  \insertdocumentendpage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: What is the use of the `\ifthenelse` conditional at the beginning of the TikZ picture?

Comment: It's been a while since I wrote this, and I'm not so sure this is needed. Did you try replacing the conditional with just the false statement, e.g. `\newcommand{\TCA}{\Progressbar@TodoB !\Progressbar@Completion !\Progressbar@TodoA}
                    \newcommand{\TCB}{\Progressbar@TodoB}
                    \newcommand{\DCA}{\Progressbar@DoneA}
                    \newcommand{\DCB}{\Progressbar@DoneB !\Progressbar@Completion !\Progressbar@DoneA}`?

Comment: It would seem that only the false part of the conditional matters. But I'm getting some erratic behavior when I change the `Todo` and `Done` colors; the transition of colors is not working, and I don't know why...

Comment: @KevinC: Please see my update, now it should work ;D

Comment: Thanks! Clipping is a very clever way indeed! And `\colorlet` is also more robust in dealing with the colors than `\newcommand`. 
With regard to the old method, I also managed to get a "smooth" color transition by setting `TCA` and `DCR` equal to `DoneB!\Progressbar@Completion!TodoA`. Anyway, this is an excellent implementation of progress bar `:)`

Answer (score 15):

My implementation gives you a both navigation and progress bar: you could jump to any frame by clicking some navigation box.

[image: Beamer Theme Mathz]

First save the following codes as **beamerouterthemeprogress.sty** file:

```
\makeatletter

\AtBeginSection[]{\frame{\sectionpage}}
\AtBeginSubsection[]{\frame{\subsectionpage}}

\newcommand{\my@bigsize}{9}
\newcommand{\my@medsize}{7}
\newcommand{\my@smallsize}{5}

\newlength{\my@tempsize}

\newcounter{my@sectnum}

\newcommand{\my@lastdigit}[1]{%
  \loop\ifnum\value{#1}>9\addtocounter{#1}{-10}\repeat
  \arabic{#1}%
}

\newcommand\my@fixedbox[2]{%
  \makebox[#1]{\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.25ex}#2}%
}

\newcommand\my@colorbox[3]{%
  {\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\colorbox{#1}{\my@fixedbox{#2}{#3}}}%
}

\def\my@temptext{}

\newcommand{\my@navbox}[1][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \def\my@tempbox{\my@fixedbox}%
  \else
    \def\my@tempbox{\my@colorbox{#1}}%
  \fi
  \ifx\my@box\my@bigbox
    \def\my@temptext{\my@lastdigit{my@sectnum}}%
  \fi
  \ifx\my@box\my@medbox
    \def\my@temptext{$\diamond$}%
  \fi
  \ifx\my@box\my@smallbox
    \def\my@temptext{$-$}%
  \fi
  \my@tempbox{\my@tempsize}{\my@temptext}%
}

\defbeamertemplate{navigation box}{home}{%
  \setlength{\my@tempsize}{\my@box@size pt}%
  \my@colorbox{teal!60}{\my@tempsize}{$\equiv$}%
}

\defbeamertemplate{navigation box}{done}{%
  \setlength{\my@tempsize}{\my@box@size pt}%
  \my@navbox[teal!60]%
}

\defbeamertemplate{navigation box}{todo}{%
  \setlength{\my@tempsize}{\my@box@size pt}%
  \my@navbox
}

\newcommand{\my@bigbox}{\global\let\my@box@size=\my@bigsize\usebeamertemplate{navigation box}}
\newcommand{\my@medbox}{\global\let\my@box@size=\my@medsize\usebeamertemplate{navigation box}}
\newcommand{\my@smallbox}{\global\let\my@box@size=\my@smallsize\usebeamertemplate{navigation box}}

\renewcommand{\sectionentry}[5]{\global\let\my@box=\my@bigbox\setcounter{my@sectnum}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\beamer@subsectionentry}[5]{\global\let\my@box=\my@medbox}

\renewcommand{\slideentry}[6]{%
  \def\my@temp@i{1/1}%
  \def\my@temp@ii{#4}%
  \ifx\my@temp@i\my@temp@ii % title page
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation box}[home]%
  \else
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation box}[done]%
  \fi
  \ifnum\c@section<#1%
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation box}[todo]%
  \else
    \ifnum\c@section=#1\ifnum\c@subsection<#2%
      \setbeamertemplate{navigation box}[todo]%
    \else
      \ifnum\c@subsection=#2\ifnum\c@subsectionslide<#3%
        \setbeamertemplate{navigation box}[todo]%
      \fi\fi
    \fi\fi
  \fi
  \ifx\my@temp@i\my@temp@ii % title page
    \beamer@link(#4){\my@bigbox}%
  \else
    \beamer@link(#4){\my@box}%
  \fi
  \global\let\my@box=\my@smallbox
}

\defbeamertemplate{footline}{progress}
{%
  {\color{teal}\hrule}\hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.8\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,left]{footline}%
    \kern2em\dohead
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{footline}%
    \insertframenumber{}/\inserttotalframenumber\kern2em
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }%
}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[progress]

\makeatother
```

Then you could create a beamer file for testing this outer theme (put it in the same folder as **beamerouterthemeprogress.sty** file):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme{progress}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=lightgray}

\begin{document}

\title{Beamer Theme Math}
\author{Author Name}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Name One}

\subsection{Subname One}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subname Two}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subname Three}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\section{Name Two}

\subsection{Subname One}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subname Two}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subname Three}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\section{Name Three}

\subsection{Subname One}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subname Two}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subname Three}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame \insertframenumber
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I notice one problem. The document must have at least one `subsection` to compile properly.

Comment: @pushpen.paul Fixed. Please try it again.

Comment: one mild inconvenience (matter of taste) I observed is that the progress bar includes the appendix. background: I normally use `appendixnumberbeamer` to only the main body count for the total number of frames. otherwise one might scare off listeners at the start when they see a page count that's inflated by backup material.

Comment: report one problem: when presenting too many pages the bar will be truncated, better to set the total length propotional to paperwidth

Comment: Hi @L.J.R., this is quite an old post, but I really liked your solution to this problem. Do you know of a way to make your progress bar work with other themes? Which part of the code would I need for that? I already like my current theme and don't want to change it except for adding your progress bar. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Here a simple footline template

```
\setbeamercolor{progress bar progress}{use=progress bar,bg=progress bar.fg}
\defbeamertemplate{footline}{progress bar}{
  \dimen0=\paperwidth
  \multiply\dimen0 by \insertframenumber
  \divide\dimen0 by \inserttotalframenumber
  \edef\progressbarwidth{\the\dimen0}

  \leavevmode%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=1.75ex,dp=1ex]{progress bar}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\progressbarwidth,ht=1.75ex,dp=1ex]{progress bar progress}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
```

which can then be used as follows

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[progress bar]
\setbeamercolor{progress bar}{fg=blue!50!black,bg=white!50!black}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: You might want to get the `\newdimen` out of the definition as it would define everytime it is executed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! After reading about what `\newdimen` does I decided to remove it and use a scratch register instead.

Comment: +1 For simplicity. Thank you.

Comment: @Friedrich  Can we add Page numbers in this bar too simultaneously?

Comment: Sure, I have used this before: https://gist.github.com/friedrich/538ed40acb9a1c7582470e01387fc867

Answer (score 6):

This is a very short "answer", but it fits the purpose:

There is a very "unobtrusive progressbar" included in the `metropolis` beamer theme. The progressbar is a liiiittle bit too unobtrusive for my taste<strike>, but I haven't found out how to make it thicker, yet</strike>.

Usage example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%The used theme. Options: No page number, progress bar at the bottom
\usetheme[numbering=none,progressbar=foot]{metropolis}
```

---

**Addendum**: To adapt the thickness ("width", for the initiated), I use

```
\makeatletter
    \setlength{\metropolis@progressinheadfoot@linewidth}{1pt}
\makeatother
```

from an [answer by samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/369852/117274), in which samcarter also explains how to work with the other progressbars (section pages and such) in the metropolis theme.