# Combining progress bars for latex-beamer

Tags: beamer

@GonzaloMedina has posted a nice example (see [Progress bar for latex-beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59742/progress-bar-for-latex-beamer)) on how to put a progress bar in a beamer presentation.

I would like to have the bar from the first example (the blue and shaded), but with the numbering from the third example (the `fraction'-like). I would really appreciate it, if someone will create a MWE for me where this is implemented.

P.S. I hope that this is a okay way of asking questions---I had my first try on [Progress bar for latex-beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59742/progress-bar-for-latex-beamer). Am I still wrong, let me know and I will try to improve my question technique.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The quickest fix seems to be finding the lines

```
\draw[color=normal text.fg!50]  
      (0pt, 0pt) rectangle (\progressbar@pbwd, \progressbar@pbht) 
        node[pos=0.5,color=normal text.fg] {\textnormal{%
             \pgfmathparse{\insertframenumber*100/\inserttotalframenumber}%
             \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}\,\%%
        }%
    };
```

in the first one and changing it to

```
\draw[color=normal text.fg!50]  
  (0pt, 0pt) rectangle (\progressbar@pbwd, \progressbar@pbht) 
    node[pos=0.5,color=normal text.fg] {%
         \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber%
};
```

[image]