# Add an progress bar image based on page number

Tags: beamer, graphics, header-footer, presentations

I would like to add a "progress bar" to each page of my report. I have 25 images named pbar1.png to pbar25.png, as shown below, to be put on slides:

pbar1.png: [image: pbar1.png]

pbar12.png: [image: pbar12.png]

pbar25.png: [image: pbar25.png]

Because I have exactly 25 images, but my report may have more pages (or less), I map the page number to image number using a simple linear map:

[image]

I can do the calculations using `calc`. My problem is to determine how many pages there are. I can use `lastpage` package or just simply add a label at the end of the pages and call `\pageref{lastpagenum}`, but then when I run LaTeX on the file for the first time, the reference is undefined and I get an `Arithmatic overflow` error (as it appears in the denominator of the fraction). I tried using `\getrefbykeydefault{lastpagenum}{page}{1400}` from `refcount` to avoid getting zero, but that didn't help. I also tried `\ifstrequal`, which didn't help either.

Here is the MWE. Some comments are provided in the code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{imagenum}
\newcounter{dummy}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{
    % 1400 below can be replaced with any number number big enough
    \setcounter{dummy}{\getrefbykeydefault{lastpagenum}{page}{1400}-1}
    % To run without error, replace \thedummy below with 3 (which is 4-1)
    \setcounter{imagenum}{(\thepage-1)*\ratio{24 cm}{\thedummy cm} +1}
    %\includegraphics{../../../_Common/ProgressBar/pbar\theimagenum.png} 
    % includegraphics above clearly won't work. So simply just print the scaled image number
    \theimagenum
    }

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\newpage

\lipsum[1]\newpage

\lipsum[1]\newpage

\lipsum[1]

\label{lastpagenum}
\end{document}
```

Comment: set last page number to, let's say, 1000 in beginning of document.

Comment: Related [Progress bar for latex-beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59742/15717) and it's linked Q's and [The progressbar Beamer theme](http://recherche.noiraudes.net/fr/LaTeX.php)

Comment: @Eddy_Em, but `lastpagenum` is not defined as a counter.

Comment: @texenthusiast, Interesting that I searched for many combinations of keywords, but missed the obvious one that would include "progress bar."

Comment: hint: [beamer tag search](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beamer), look at first one. hence tagging/title is very important on SX

Comment: @texenthusiast, I'm having second thoughts about the `beamer` tag, because the solution/question is not really limited to `beamer`, nor does it need `beamer`. It can well be used for other document styles. I certainly agree with your point though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply check whether the `lastpage` reference (i.e. `\r@lastpagenum`) is defined (using the `\ifdefined` macro) before performing your calculations:

```
\makeatletter% required as some of the commands we will use contain "@" in their name
\lhead{
  % only perform the calculations if the "lastpagenum" reference is defined
  \ifdefined\r@lastpagenum%
    % 1400 below can be replaced with any number number big enough
    \setcounter{dummy}{\getrefbykeydefault{lastpagenum}{page}{1400}-1}%
    \setcounter{imagenum}{(\thepage-1)*\ratio{24 cm}{\thedummy cm} +1}%
    %\includegraphics{../../../_Common/ProgressBar/pbar\theimagenum.png} 
    \theimagenum%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
```

The next step is to remove the use of the dummy counter, by getting / converting the last page reference into a number that can be used inside the calculations, using `refcount`'s `\getpagerefnumber`:

```
\makeatletter% required as some of the commands we will use contain "@" in their name
\lhead{
  % only perform the calculations if the "lastpagenum" reference is defined
  \ifdefined\r@lastpagenum%
    \setcounter{imagenum}{(\thepage-1)*24/(\getpagerefnumber{lastpagenum}-1) +1}%
    %\includegraphics{../../../_Common/ProgressBar/pbar\theimagenum.png} 
    \theimagenum%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I was just doing the same (removing `dummy`) but you beat me to it. Just a minor modification to keep the equation correct: `\setcounter{imagenum}{(\thepage-1)*24/(\getpagerefnumber{lastpagenum}-1) + 1}`

Comment: @AliMehrizi Indeed; somehow that `-1` got removed too :)

Comment: I'm accepting your answer. Probably one of the fastest complete accepted answers on TeX.SX!

Comment: @AliMehrizi I was just refreshing the unanswered list a last time before going to bed :)