# How to make a right side progress bar in LaTeX?

Tags: beamer, presentations, animations, animate

I liked the bar of the first answer in this question:

[Progress bar for latex-beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59742/progress-bar-for-latex-beamer)

so my question is if there is a way to put this progress bar in the right/left side of the slides.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! While this might seem nice, I'd discourage you from doing it. The attendance will be attracted by the sand clock more than to your presentation.

Comment: yes, I know, but it is for people to not despair by don't know the time remaining.

Comment: there are lots of progress bar examples here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59742/progress-bar-for-latex-beamer. If you have a drawing paste the code it and our users can make it interactive.

Comment: oh, that's what I meant, there's a way to put this bar on the right?

Comment: I think it should be doable however please make a specific question instead of a moving target. Then it will get pretty confusing to everyone because most of the comments won't make sense if we change the content of the question. Pick one of those make your own two-slide document and ask for the changes you want. Otherwise I will do something then you will ask for a color change etc. See other questions on this site how we provide code to each other both when asking and answering such that we are always on the same page.

Comment: do you think I should delete this question then?

Comment: Not really. It didn't get an answer yet so you can change it and make it completely different now with the code you have to ask *how to place the progress bar on the left* or something like that.

Comment: Without knowing which of the 12 different progress bars from 9 answers you are referring to, it will need a psychic to answer this.