# beamer: pages in the sidebar

Tags: beamer, templates

Do you know if the template used in the following slides is publicly available? Or a similar one I can adapt?

http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~az/lectures/cv/adaboost_matas.pdf

If not, any suggestion on how I should go about to implement it?

Maybe using a tikz overlay on the side of the slide and somehow setting the height to fill the page? How do I then avoid the contents from crossing the sidebar?

(ps: I am not asking people to develop the template for me. Just a suggestion on how I should approach this problem, or if a total or partial solution is available somewhere. I have developed a couple of templates myself, but very minor stuff.)

Update 1: for future reference, here is the snapshot of the slides in the link:

[image: slides]

Comment: I understand that using a `sidebar` in beamer changes frame margins and frame contents doesn't overlap it. And about page information on sidebar, it looks like a [`progress bar`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59742/progress-bar-for-latex-beamer/59806#59806) but vertically oriented.

Comment: the page gives me a 404 Error...

Comment: It was probably a temporary downtime. Tell me if it persists.

Comment: @Knigge46, I have posted a screenshot of the template I have in mind.

Comment: To prevent your content to overlap with your sidebar, try to adjust the margins `\setbeamersize{text margin left=17.4mm,text margin right=7.4mm}`

Comment: The itemization symbols can be modified similar to `\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\rule[1.6mm]{2.2mm}{2.2mm}~}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\rule[1mm]{2mm}{2mm}~}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{\rule[0.5mm]{1mm}{1mm}~}`

Comment: What happens if you have more than 16 frames? Will the boxes get smaller or will only a part of the frames be visible in the sidebar?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion guys. I have posted my solution as an answer using your suggestions. @Ignasi

Comment: @samcarter yes, I think the sidebar should expand; try the answer below. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay guys, here is a version of the template I meant:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\Tiny=\tiny


\title{Title}
\author{Ricardo Cruz}
\date{}

\usepackage{tikz}

%% SIDEBAR

\newlength\swidth
\setlength\swidth{1.2cm}    

\newlength\theight
\setlength\theight{1.0cm}   

\makeatletter
\newlength\beamerleftmargin
\setlength\beamerleftmargin{\Gm@lmargin}
\makeatother

\newlength\sheight

\setbeamersize{sidebar width right=\swidth}
\setbeamerfont{sidebar right}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{%
\vspace{\theight}
\ifnum\inserttotalframenumber > 1
    \setlength\sheight{\dimexpr(\paperheight-\theight)/(\inserttotalframenumber-1)\relax}
\fi
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=\sheight]
    \foreach \i in {2,...,\inserttotalframenumber} {
        \def\pgnbr{\inserttotalframenumber - \i-1}
        \ifnum\i=\insertframenumber
            \filldraw[very thick] (0,\pgnbr) rectangle (\swidth,\pgnbr+1);
            \node[white,anchor=mid,font=\bfseries] at (\swidth/2,\pgnbr+0.5) {\hyperlink{Navigation\i}{\number\numexpr\i-1}};
        \else
            \draw[very thick] (0,\pgnbr) rectangle (\swidth-0.07cm,\pgnbr+1);
            \node[anchor=mid,font=\bfseries] at (\swidth/2,\pgnbr+0.5) {\hyperlink{Navigation\i}{\number\numexpr\i-1}};
        \fi
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
}

%% TITLE

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\Large\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\hspace{-\beamerleftmargin}
\draw[very thick] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth-0.08cm,\theight-0.05cm);
\node[anchor=mid] at (\paperwidth/2,\theight/2) {\insertframetitle};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

%% ITEMIZE (@samcarter)

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\rule[1.6mm]{2.2mm}{2.2mm}~}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\rule[1mm]{2mm}{2mm}~}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{\rule[0.5mm]{1mm}{1mm}~}

%%

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}{First}
\label{frame1}
First
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Second}
\label{frame2}
Second
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Third}
\label{frame3}
Third
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Clicking page numbers work and everything. Some white padding is a bit hacky, and it requires two runs to compile. But it's looking pretty cool. :)