# beamertheme metropolis: Change Progressbar Line Width

Tags: beamer

- I am using the very nice beamer theme metropolis, see https://ctan.org/pkg/beamertheme-metropolis or https://github.com/matze/mtheme.
- I like the `progressbar` option but it is too subtle for me.
- **Question:** How to increase the line width of the progress bar? Ideally, without modifying the style file.
- In the **screenshot**, the **progress bar** is **orange** and barely visible.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% https://ctan.org/pkg/beamertheme-metropolis
\usetheme[
        sectionpage = progressbar,
        progressbar = frametitle,
        background = dark,
    ]{metropolis}
    
\title{Title}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{1. Section}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title 1}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{2. Section}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title 2}
Hello, world!
\end{frame}

\section{3. Section}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title 3}
Hello, world!
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Update

My question is a duplicate of [How to change width of progress bar in beamer metropolis theme?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577201).

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577201
\makeatletter
\setlength{\metropolis@titleseparator@linewidth}{2pt}
\setlength{\metropolis@progressonsectionpage@linewidth}{2pt}
\setlength{\metropolis@progressinheadfoot@linewidth}{2pt}
\makeatother
```