# change bar in metropolis theme title

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

I use this code for a metropolis beamer presentation (thanks to a user here!)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{76,138,225}

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=red,bg=lightgray!50}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=lightgray!25}
\setbeamercolor{progress bar in section page}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=orange}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]

% ----------------------------------------------------------
% Einstellungen Titelfolien
\title{Aufbau von tragfähigen Grundvorstellungen zu diskreten Zufallsvariablen}
\subtitle{Untertitel zu bestimmen}
% \date{\today}
\author{author}
\date{date}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
  
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
    abc
  
  \begin{definition}[test]
  content...
  \end{definition}
  
  \begin{itemize}
  \item test
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame} 

\section{title}
  

    
\end{document}
```

It produces a orange bar on the titlepage. Does anyone know how to change the color to blue? See in the picture, I wish the line to be blue.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities:

- `\setbeamercolor{progress bar}{fg=myblue}` will change the colour of all progress bars, be it on the title or section pages
- `\setbeamercolor{title separator}{fg=myblue}` will only change the colour on the title page

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{76,138,225}

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=red,bg=lightgray!50}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=lightgray!25}
\setbeamercolor{progress bar}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=orange}
%\setbeamercolor{title separator}{fg=myblue}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]

% ----------------------------------------------------------
% Einstellungen Titelfolien
\title{Aufbau von tragfähigen Grundvorstellungen zu diskreten Zufallsvariablen}
\subtitle{Untertitel zu bestimmen}
% \date{\today}
\author{author}
\date{date}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
  
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
    abc
  
  \begin{definition}[test]
  content...
  \end{definition}
  
  \begin{itemize}
  \item test
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame} 

\section{title}
  

    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your support and knowledge about beamer is just awesome, thanks alot :)
Just another short question. Is it possible to change the thickness of the progress bars (both on the title page and the section pages)?

Comment: @montarenbici https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/369852/36296