# Up to down Progress bar

Tags: beamer

I was looking for a nice `beamer` presentation. But I didn't like any of them. Nearly a mixture of them was good, but there is a matter it seems that there was no previous example for progress bar in side bars.
There was examples for side bar in 
[Progress bar for latex-beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59742/progress-bar-for-latex-beamer)
is it possible to have text navigation sidebar in left and progress bar (up to down) in right?
Here it is a my MWE.

```
\documentclass[10pt, compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\title{Report}
\subtitle{}
\date{\today}
\author{V A}
\institute{Lab}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\useoutertheme{sidebar}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\makeatletter
\def\progressbar@progressbar{}  % the progress bar
\newcount\progressbar@tmpcounta % auxiliary counter
\newcount\progressbar@tmpcountb % auxiliary counter
\newdimen\progressbar@pbht      % progressbar height
\newdimen\progressbar@pbwd      % progressbar width
\newdimen\progressbar@tmpdim    % auxiliary dimension
\progressbar@pbwd=20em
\progressbar@pbht=0.5pt
\def\progressbar@progressbar{%
  \progressbar@tmpcounta=\insertframenumber
  \progressbar@tmpcountb=\inserttotalframenumber
  \progressbar@tmpdim=\progressbar@pbwd
  \multiply\progressbar@tmpdim by \progressbar@tmpcounta
  \divide\progressbar@tmpdim by \progressbar@tmpcountb    
  \makebox[\textwidth][c]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tight background]    
      \node[anchor=west, white, inner sep=0pt] at (0pt, 0pt) {\insertsectionHEAD};

      \draw[anchor=west, mDarkBrown, fill=mDarkBrown, inner sep=0pt]
      (2pt, -16pt) rectangle ++ (\progressbar@pbwd, \progressbar@pbht);    
      \draw[anchor=west, mMediumBrown, fill=mMediumBrown, inner sep=0pt]
      (2pt, -16pt) rectangle ++ (\progressbar@tmpdim, \progressbar@pbht);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \section{E1}
    \begin{frame}{F1}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}{F2}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show what you've tried so far as a minimal working (compilable) code example (MWE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a quick hack one can combine the code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59749/36296 with a sidebar theme:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berkeley}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\colorlet{pbblue}{beamer@blendedblue}% filling color for the progress bar
\definecolor{pbgray}{HTML}{575757}% background color for the progress bar


\def\progressbar@progressbar{} % the progress bar
\newcount\progressbar@tmpcounta% auxiliary counter
\newcount\progressbar@tmpcountb% auxiliary counter
\newdimen\progressbar@pbht %progressbar height
\newdimen\progressbar@pbwd %progressbar width
\newdimen\progressbar@tmpdim % auxiliary dimension

\progressbar@pbwd=.82\paperheight
\progressbar@pbht=1.5ex

% the progress bar
\def\progressbar@progressbar{%

    \progressbar@tmpcounta=\insertframenumber
    \progressbar@tmpcountb=\inserttotalframenumber
    \progressbar@tmpdim=\progressbar@pbwd
    \multiply\progressbar@tmpdim by \progressbar@tmpcounta
    \divide\progressbar@tmpdim by \progressbar@tmpcountb

  \begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners=2pt,very thin]

    \shade[top color=pbgray!40,bottom color=pbgray!40,middle color=pbgray!50]
      (0pt, 0pt) rectangle ++ (\progressbar@pbwd, \progressbar@pbht);

      \shade[draw=structure.fg,top color=structure.fg,bottom color=structure.fg,middle color=structure.fg!75!black] %
        (0pt, 0pt) rectangle ++ (\progressbar@tmpdim, \progressbar@pbht);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\rotatebox{270}{\progressbar@progressbar}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{test}

\begin{frame}{title}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]